# Python Crypto RSA, 127 bytes length cipher with a 1024 bits key

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

When I test RSA encryption on my laptop using PyCrypto (Archlinux, package: python-crypto/python2-crypto), I used a 1024 key generated by RSA module to encrypt a random data, and it  produced a 127 bytes length cipher.

A simple code following: (I got the values when debugging)

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
pubkey = b'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDq+qbaMTZtPH3LuXLrAn37YGzc\ngrL7ieTILtkXTl5PIozJUQZ06bQXr/uS+FtvYNSvaT53ZpSyKmVmWtoX7lFzA6FW\nsILFTgFUDNRnPIQv1rQb16wi694rKPRe1uIr8/hthXtTec8b2aJovizQOlkXY0Pq\nZohNGofi02xlUD8KsQIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'
prikey = b'-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIICXgIBAAKBgQDq+qbaMTZtPH3LuXLrAn37YGzcgrL7ieTILtkXTl5PIozJUQZ0\n6bQXr/uS+FtvYNSvaT53ZpSyKmVmWtoX7lFzA6FWsILFTgFUDNRnPIQv1rQb16wi\n694rKPRe1uIr8/hthXtTec8b2aJovizQOlkXY0PqZohNGofi02xlUD8KsQIDAQAB\nAoGBAMkKEI0ng8Br+9i8XqTQ6gaTVjBHpmhtbw8SfexhwXCFR9zJ9PM8LDgD+gKh\neGFPgEhfi/FOE7Rnb3/mBShqXsWbqz7STJ05GOxtKo+L1z5K7X4E9WmVjIEVU46I\nhF43LJQvoDjQRbZh2cUMSYUR8+LqJJd6MFdhLJhEIf+LhCbBAkEA71lRBiSwZH/8\nsaUE4qZ/vxkS65czBcWLSCgn+7D/kvunX1hxqi3zTxMn4gyluw3IICzvLFgdDG6f\nUZk23aDcyQJBAPtTgvi4lYAIoeh6Xx8NZxroVNVBlP9BzJTBCcnX1Ym0aC/p+6n8\n7Lu9bkKk/hb0r7Oy76wzxObWv9uvRQNp+qkCQQCoOy8oEkGpYgxLEKIObNj9iLIz\nxWKne+IaJZ902UPKG/fYnGHIK+QIgH5X9GvIvjcb5nl1wbkpM9fnkrltrdOBAkBe\n7LbuHEGTHy+P8BBXWSeVOSU5etC87GxJzvNUginMHhCv8C82kCoV6sFneIvjvb1T\nIQV3RAJdscS7Q+LMHE4pAkEAzp2o8+2+9QJwzkpxGyNjJ7ZECQsZIb7MOH7LYhX0\ncnwffXFt4ttcwbyX2SdhCVPBDkczkJkOzcnEqtjoWt+dBw==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

pub = RSA.importKey(pubkey)
data = b'\xc9\xc5\xa9\x1b\xc2\x0f\x05\xf0\xe3\xe1W\x9d\x94b\xc6 '
cipher = pub.encrypt(data, 0)[0]
print(len(cipher))
```

This will print 127 (normally it would be 128 for 1024 bits key), and I don't know why.

Comment: the `encrypt` method simply suppresses all leading zero bytes. You can reconstitute these easily enough if you want.

Comment: oh, I see. And that is why it would suggest to use Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP/PKCS1_v1_5 to instead.Thanks~

Comment: @GregS That's not really a solution as it will leave you with an insecure algorithm, although totran already seems to have found it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a correct encryption scheme. From the documentation:

> Even though you may choose to directly use the methods of an RSA key object to perform the primitive cryptographic operations (e.g. `_RSAobj.encrypt`), it is recommended to use one of the standardized schemes instead (like `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5` or `Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5`).

although nowadays the more modern/safe `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP` should be preferred over `Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5`.

If you use one of these schemes then the output will always be 128 bytes. The reason for that is that PKCS#1 specifies a function called I2OSP, which converts the result of the modular exponentiation (which is a number bounded by the modulus/the key size) to a static number of octets, the key size to be exact.

The output of the direct encrypt function is what is called raw or textbook RSA: just modular exponentiation. This will just return the number, which may have leading zero bits. How many depends on chance, (somewhat) on the value of the modulus and if signed or unsigned encoding is used.

Comment: OK, so you already found the alternative, but I guess some additional explanation was in order, especially for other readers :)